# Looping over an array in RapidJson and getting the object elements

Tags: c++, rapidjson

How do I get the value out of a ConstrValueIterator? In this case I know that the elements of the array are dictionaries (aka objects).

Code summed up:

```
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator itr = rawbuttons.Begin(); itr != rawbuttons.End(); ++itr) { // Ok
    if (itr->HasMember("yes")) { // Ok
        auto somestring = itr["yes"]->GetString(); // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um. Iterators need to be dereferenced or whatever it's called.

```
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator itr = rawbuttons.Begin(); itr != rawbuttons.End(); ++itr) { // Ok
    if (itr->HasMember("yes")) { // Ok
        auto somestring = (*itr)["yes"]->GetString(); // bingo
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider marking your own answer correct if it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator itr = rawbuttons.Begin(); itr != rawbuttons.End(); ++itr) { 
if (itr->HasMember("yes")) { 
    auto somestring = (*itr)["yes"].GetString(); 
}}
```